# Jquery Ajax not giving a response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the  following jQuery script which is supposed to fetch data from my server:

```
$(".login_button").click(function () {
    var username = $(".username").val();
    var userkey = $(".userkey").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.0.12LMISWebservices/Validation?username=" + username + "&userkey=" + userkey + "",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {
            var program = response.program_code;
            alert(program);


        },
        error: function (response) {
           console.error(response);
        }
    });
});
```

And the data returned is in the following mock data:

```
{
  "Programs": [
    {
      "program_code": "Malaria",
      "program_name": "Malaria",
      "program_id": 2
    },
    {
      "program_code": "CD4",
      "program_name": "Laboratory Monitoring Reagents",
      "program_id": 6
    },
    {
      "program_code": "LAB",
      "program_name": "Test Kits",
      "program_id": 8
    },
    {
      "program_code": "ART",
      "program_name": "ART ",
      "program_id": 3
    },
    {
      "program_code": "TB & Leprosy",
      "program_name": "TB & Leprosy",
      "program_id": 5
    },
    {
      "program_code": "Nutri",
      "program_name": "Nutrition",
      "program_id": 7
    },
    {
      "program_code": "FP",
      "program_name": "Family Planning",
      "program_id": 1
    },
    {
      "program_code": "EMMS",
      "program_name": "Essential Medicines & Medical Supplies",
      "program_id": 4
    },
    {
      "program_code": "test3",
      "program_name": "FP Test",
      "program_id": 15
    }
  ],
  "facility_name": "",
  "profile_message": "ok",
  "mfl_code": "",
  "user_status": true,
  "facility_id": "",
  "login_as": "Patrick K M"
}
```

**How can I get the  data from the  response and alert it on my screen?**

Comment: Are you getting the response?

Comment: You seem to missing a `/` here: `http://192.168.0.12`/`LMISWebservices/`

Comment: do you want to show each "program_code"?

Comment: To debug this sort of thing, look in DevTools, the request would have failed.

Comment: What error you are getting in console as per code `error: function (response) {
           console.error(response);
        }`. Or have a look over the domain name `http://192.168.0.12LMISWebservices`

Comment: if  you just want to be able to print out the received json you could use JSON.stringify(reponse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this. this is not run here because cross domain but try in your code that work perfectly.

```js
$(".login_button").click(function() {
  var username = $(".username").val();
  var userkey = $(".userkey").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://192.168.0.12/LMISWebservices/Validation?username=" + username + "&userkey=" + userkey + "",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response) {
      //your JSON give list there for male loop throug each.
      $.each(response.Programs,function(i,item){
        alert(item.program_code);
      });

    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.error(response);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="username"/>
<input type="text" class="userkey"/>
<input type="button" value="GET" class="login_button">
```

Comment: A little bit more clarification on what changed and why would improve your post and potentially get your more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a typo in your URL. You have no forward slash after the last part of the IP address.

```
url: "http://192.168.0.12
```

Comment: I really think this could have been better as a comment. It could pay off if you are right, but right now it's just a guess.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe it should be a comment. However it is the only visible issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax url is missing a `/` between ip and folder name http://192.168.0.12 `/` LMISWebservices/...

Try This

```
$(".login_button").click(function () {
                var username = $(".username").val();
                var userkey = $(".userkey").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://192.168.0.12/LMISWebservices/Validation?username=" + username + "&userkey=" + userkey + "",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        //var program = response.program_code;
                        //alert(program);


                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                       console.error(response);
                    }
                });
            });
```